# AWS CodeArtifact maven deploy failing with Unauthorized (401)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, aws-codeartifact

I have created a AWS CodeArtifact repository, and would like to upload some artefacts to it, however when I try do so I get the following error:

**Error**

```
status code: 401, reason phrase: Unauthorized (401)
```

I have the following configuration on AWS CodeDeploy (using [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/maven-mvn.html) AWS documentation as a guideline).

Domain: `uat-myco` and Repository: `uat-myco-repository`.

On my local machine, I try to use `mvn deploy` to upload an artefact to the repo.

**.m2/settings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd"
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>uat-myco-uat-myco-repository</id>
      <username>aws</username>
      <password>${env.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN}</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>uat-myco-uat-myco-repository</id>
      <name>uat-myco-uat-myco-repository</name>
      <url>https://uat-myco-domainownerid.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/uat-myco-repository/</url>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <proxies>
  </proxies>
  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>uat-myco-uat-myco-repository</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>uat-myco-uat-myco-repository</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>uat-myco-uat-myco-repository</id>
          <url>https://uat-myco-domainownerid.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/uat-myco-repository/</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

As per the AWS CodeDeploy instructions, I set up the `CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN` as follows (valid for 12 hrs):

```
export CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN='aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain uat-myco --domain-owner domainownerid --region us-east-1 --query authorizationToken --output text'
```

Note: `domainownerid` = the Domain owner id (number removed for privacy reasons)

I then try deploy an artefact to the repo:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=myco-osgi-bom          \
-DartifactId=myco-osgi-bom       \
-Dversion=1.0                  \
-Dfile=/Users/user/.m2/repository/com/myco/integration/myco-osgi-bom/1.0/myco-osgi-bom-1.0.pom   \
-Dpackaging=xml                \
-DrepositoryId=uat-myco-uat-myco-repository    \
-Durl=https://uat-myco-domainownerid.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/uat-myco-repository/
```

**Output**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from uat-myco-uat-myco-repository: https://uat-myco-domainownerid.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/uat-myco-repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/3.2.0/maven-clean-plugin-3.2.0.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.2.0: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:3.2.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:3.2.0

[WARNING] org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml failed to transfer from https://uat-myco-domainownerid.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/uat-myco-repository/ during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of uat-myco-uat-myco-repository has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to uat-myco-uat-myco-repository (https://uat-myco-domainownerid.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/uat-myco-repository/): status code: 401, reason phrase: Unauthorized (401)

[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'deploy' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/richardmarais/.m2/repository), uat-myco-uat-myco-repository (https://uat-myco-domainownerid.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/maven/uat-myco-repository/)] -> [Help 1]
```

**More Info**

I run the following from the cmd line to see if the token can be generated.

```
$ aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain uat-myco --domain-owner domainownerid --region us-east-1 --query authorizationToken --output text

An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

**Policy**

I did try setting up a Repository policy to give full access, but this made no difference:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::domainownerid:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "codeartifact:AssociateExternalConnection",
                "codeartifact:CopyPackageVersions",
                "codeartifact:DeletePackageVersions",
                "codeartifact:DeletePackage",
                "codeartifact:DeleteRepository",
                "codeartifact:DeleteRepositoryPermissionsPolicy",
                "codeartifact:DescribePackageVersion",
                "codeartifact:DescribeRepository",
                "codeartifact:DisassociateExternalConnection",
                "codeartifact:DisposePackageVersions",
                "codeartifact:GetPackageVersionReadme",
                "codeartifact:GetRepositoryEndpoint",
                "codeartifact:ListPackageVersionAssets",
                "codeartifact:ListPackageVersionDependencies",
                "codeartifact:ListPackageVersions",
                "codeartifact:ListPackages",
                "codeartifact:PublishPackageVersion",
                "codeartifact:PutPackageMetadata",
                "codeartifact:PutRepositoryPermissionsPolicy",
                "codeartifact:ReadFromRepository",
                "codeartifact:UpdatePackageVersionsStatus",
                "codeartifact:UpdateRepository"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#1. Make sure you have the right access to AWS:

```
echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

export CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN='aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain my_domain --domain-owner 111122223333 --query authorizationToken --output text'
```

#2. You can also try to setup an AWS profile on your environment [Configure the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html)

```
export CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN='aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain my_domain --domain-owner 111122223333 --query authorizationToken --output text **--profile profile-name**'
```

#3. Print your token before use it

```
echo $CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN

cat .m2/settings.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I needed to set my AWS access keys in the `~/.aws/credentials` file. It just had the default keys from aws cli installation, so I set it to the keys for my AWS user that set up codeDeploy, ad now it can generate the token successfully.

e.g.

```
aws_access_key_id=xxx
aws_secret_access_key=xxxx
```